# Best model selection (after using several methods)

Tags: r, regression, model-selection

I have 30 variables and am trying to select the best model. I have run the following methods on a 'large' data set (having removed a smaller test set):

- OLS,
- best subset selection,
- stepwise selection,
- ridge regression,
- LASSO,
- PCR and
- PLS.

All outliers were removed from both data sets. None of the variables/response have been transformed in any way prior to running the above methods and there is little/no collinearity between variables.

I ran each model (for OLS I ran the entire 30 variable model) and computed the MSE and variance for each. They differ only by 0.001 in MSE (best = PLS, worst = stepwise) and the variance (between the best – stepwise and the worst – ridge).

**How do I now choose the best model?** I'm pretty stuck!

One idea I had is to cross validate the MSE and var on the test set, but I'm unsure about how to write this code in R.

I'm using code similar to this [website](http://cbio.ensmp.fr/~jvert/svn/tutorials/practical/linearregression/linearregression.R)'s. I'm not sure that will solve the problem though. I'm using `summary(model - y.test)^2` at the moment.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question. Too broad.

Comment: What further information can I give you to help?

Comment: (1) If you're using this test set to pick the best performing model selection procedure for your data, you need another set of hold-out data to validate the procedure in which you pick the best performing model selection procedure. (2) This isn't cross-validation (see leave-one-out or $k$-fold). (3) You say the mean-square errors differ "only" by 0.001, as if we should be nodding in agreement that it's a tiny difference - are you remembering that it has units?

Comment: And please don't take it amiss if I note from this & another of your questions that you seem to be using rather advanced techniques without demonstrating a clear understanding of the general issues involved in model selection: there is a very good introduction available (for free) called [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/).

Comment: (1) I think I may have explained myself incorrectly. I have a data set - say 1000 observations. I remove 100 and keep that as the test set. I perform stepwise (for example) on the remaining 900 observations and get a 'best' model dependant in the AIC. Then I test it on the 100 observations and get the MSE. I then use another method, e.g. LASSO, on the 900 observations and aim to reduce the mallows cp. I then test this model on the test data, get a MSE, and so on. After doing this to all methods I compare the MSE's obtained from each method. Do I still need a separate data set?

Comment: (2) I haven't cross validated anything I agree. I wasn't sure if I should cross-valdiate the model (based on the 900 data) or the 'test' MSE. (3) True - but this is what R gives - and I didn't transform anything (I just scaled the data using mean/std). How do I convert it please? No offence taken - I'll check out that intro now :)

Comment: (1) If you use one way to select & fit a model on the same data, the 900, the fit will be optimistic, & it's wise to check how much on independent test data, your 100. Suppose, though, you dream up a million different ways to select & fit a model on the 900, & then pick the one that fits the test data best - do you not think there's a large element of luck involved? The test data is no longer independent of the selection & fitting procedure & the fit of the best-fitting model will be optimistic. (2) Cross-validation uses the whole data-set; splitting into hold-out samples is an alternative.

Comment: (3) My point was just that a big or small difference in MSE doesn't have an absolute meaning; it depends on how you've measured the response.

Comment: What do you suggest I do to find and choose a suitable model to explain my response? Another idea I had was to use ANOVA to check if the 'additional' factors are significant per model which will help me choose. Not sure its the right way to go though.